# Command completion in R and python

Tags: command-line, bash, python, r

In bash terminal, I could configure the command completion by inserting these lines to the `/etc/inputrc` file:

```
$if Bash
    # Search history back and forward using page-up and page-down
    "\e[5~": history-search-backward
    "\e[6~": history-search-forward

    "\e[A": history-search-backward    # arrow up
    "\e[B": history-search-forward     # arrow down

    # Completion
    set match-hidden-files off
    set page-completions off
    set completion-query-items 350
    set show-all-if-ambiguous on

$endif
```

I wonder if there is anyway to use this feature in programs such as R and python interactive environments?

On a workstation for R, somehow I have this ability, so wonder how can I configure that for my laptop as well. The R version is:

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

So, I am sure that it is possible, but does anyone know how to set it up?

Comment: You should ask this on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry, but, I thought this is not a programming question, rather it's mainly an issue of configuration!

Comment: You should check the `.*` files like `.profile` and `.bashrc` in that workstation and check how the job is done.

Comment: @Braiam They're called dotfiles. :D

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use *bash* completion in another interactive session - you're not interacting with bash at that point.

The default python interpreter provides no autocomplete function, but you can get an improved interpreter like [IPython](http://ipython.org/) (`sudo apt-get install ipython`) which provides a range of history and autocomplete functions.

The default R interpreter provides some autocompletion. I'm not sure if you can get a better command line interpreter, but a GUI like [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) (not in repositories, download deb package from their site) provides better interactivity.

Comment: Thanks for the info, however for R, I have this ability on one workstation at work but don't have this feature on my laptop. Both systems are Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

A quick way would be to add the following lines to a script called `.pythonstartup.py` and put it in your home directory:

```py
import rlcompleter, readline
readline.parse_and_bind('tab:complete')
```

Then add the following line to your `.bashrc`:

```bsh
export PYTHONSTARTUP="/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.pythonstartup.py"
```

- Note 1: The `.bashrc` file is usually located in your home directory (`~`).
- Note 2: Replace `YOUR_USERNAME` with your actual username.

Then, all you have to do is *source* it so the changes take effect right away:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Or just open a new terminal.

Comment: This answer was very useful! I used it and updated my bashrc! However, I was trying to do something else!